# Preserving C++ / CLI handles to .NET objects in C library calls

Tags: c#, c, c++-cli, clr

I have a C# library that needs to be used as part of a straight C Win32 application.  I am trying to write a wrapper in [C++ / CLI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes#A4) that can handle the C# .NET objects.  The only problem is that the whole project can not be compiled in C++, it has to stay in C.

To solve this problem I would like to opaquely pass instances of my C# objects back to the C code so they can be passed in and used in the wrapper library calls, but I can't figure out how to do it.  For instance, I would like to do something like this:

C++ / CLI Wrapper:

```
void * ReturnObject(char *name){
  return (void *)gcnew MyObject(gcnew String(name));
}

void UseObject (void *object){
  MyObject ^handle = (MyObject ^)object;
  object -> use();
}
```

Native C code using the C++ static library:

```
int main (char **argv){
  void *obj = ReturnObject("foobar");
  UseObject(obj);
}
```

So the C code doesn't ever care what the contents of `obj` are, and doesn't even know about the CLR type `MyObject`, but it just passes around the data to maintain object persistence.  I figured this should be done with `void` pointers, but the C++ compiler doesn't want to do the casts.  I don't know if it's because of the difference between managed memory and unmanaged memory, or if I'm just not doing it correctly, but I would certainly appreciate any help.

So, to recap:
I am trying to instantiate .net objects in a C++ / CLI wrapper library, and preserve those objects in straight C code so that they can be used again in other C++ / CLI library calls that I have yet to write.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't store a handle in a void*, because the garbage collector can move the object around, making the pointer worse than useless (it will now point into some other random object).

You need to use the `gcroot` template provided by C++/CLI.  You can then store `gcroot<MyObject>*` into a `void*` and pass it to your C code.  Don't forget to properly free the `gcroot` when you're done with it, in such a way that the destructor is run.

You can also look into the `GCHandle` class, which is part of the .NET class library.  But `gcroot` is recommended in C++/CLI code (it uses `GCHandle` internally).

Comment: Ok, so I think I've got this down, but now I can't figure out how to call methods on the object.  Here is what I have:

`gcroot<myObject^>* handle = (gcroot<myObject^>*) object;`
where `object` is passed in as a void pointer.
How can I access methods and members of the object now?  When I try `handle -> someMethod()` like I would with a regular handle, the compiler just says that someMethod is not a member of gcroot<T>.

Comment: @Drewmate: You'd need `(*handle)->someMethod()`.